# Erlang/OTP pattern to ensure Composite process accepts a message only when children are done

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

Is there an Erlang/OTP pattern/library for the following problem(before I hack my own):

- At the highest level, imagine there are three components(or processes?) such that A->B->C where -> means sends a message to.
- B in terms of architecture is a composite process. It is composed of many unit processes(shown in khaki green below). Sometimes, the message chain goes from B1->B2->B3->C and sometimes it goes from B1->B4->B5->B6->B3->C.

[image: Composite Actor]

What I would like to do is:

- B can only accept the next message when all it's children processes are done i.e B receives a message I1 and depending on the message, it will choose one flow and finally C gets a message O1. Until that happens, B should not accept the message I2. This is to ensure ordering of messages so that O2 of I2 does not reach C before O1 of I1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has a few names. One is "dataflow" (as in "reactive programming" -- which is sort of an overblown ball of buzzwords if you look it up) and another is "signal simulation" (as in simulation of electrical signal switches). I am not aware of a framework for this in Erlang, because it is very straightforward to implement directly.

The issue of message ordering can be made to take care of itself, depending on how you want to write things. Erlang guarantees the ordering of message between two processes, so as long as messages travel in well-defined channels, this system-wide promise can be made to work for you. If you need some more interesting signal paths than straight lines you can force synch communication; though all Erlang message are asynchronous, you can introduce synchronous blocking on `receive` wherever you want.

If you want the "B constellation" to pass a message to C but only after its signal processing has completely run its route through the B's, you can make a signal manager which sends a message to B1, and blocks until it receives the output from B3, whence it passes the completed message on to C and checks its box for the next thing from A:

```
a_loop(B) ->
  receive {in, Data} -> B ! Data end,
  a_loop(B).

% Note the two receives here -- we are blocking for the end of processing based
% on the known Ref we send out and expect to receive back in a message match.
b_manager(B1, C) ->
  Ref = make_ref(),
  receive Data -> B1 ! {Ref, Data} end,
  receive {Ref, Result} -> C ! Result end,
  b_manager(B1, C).

b_1(B2) ->
  receive
    {Ref, Data} ->
        Mod1 = do_processing(Data),
        B2 ! {Ref, Mod1}
  end,
  b_1(B2).

% Here you have as many "b_#" processes as you need...

b_2(B) ->
  receive
    {Ref, Data} ->
        Result = do_other_processing(Data),
        B ! {Ref, Result}
  end,
  b_2(B).

c_loop() ->
  receive Result -> stuff(Result) end,
  c_loop().
```

Obviously I *drastically* simplified things -- as in this obviously doesn't include any concept of supervision -- I didn't even address how you would want to link these together (and with this little checking for liveness, you would *need* to spawn_link them so if anything dies they all die -- which is probably exactly what you want with the B subset anyway, so you can treat it as a single unit). Also, you may wind up needing a throttle in there somewhere (like at/before A, or in B). But basically speaking, this is a way of passing messages through in a way that makes B block until its segment of processing is finished.

There are other ways, like gen_event, but I find them to be less flexible than writing a actual simulation of a processing pipeline. As far as how to implement this -- I would make it a combination of OTP supervisors and gen_fsm, as these two components represent a nearly perfect parallel to signal processing components,which your system seems to be aimed at mimicking.

To discover what states you need in your gen_fsms and how you want to clump them together I would probably prototype in a *very* simplistic fashion in pure Erlang for a few hours, just to make sure I actually understand the problem, and then write my proper OTP supervisors and gen_fsms. This makes sure I don't get invested in some temple of gen_foo behaviors instead of getting invested in actually solving my problem (you're going to have to write it at least twice before its *right* anyway...).

Hopefully this gives you at least a place to start tackling your problem. In any case, this is a very natural sort of thing to do in Erlang -- and is close enough to the way the language and the problem work that it should be pretty fun to work on.

Comment: You are bang on about signal simulation :). It's supposed to be an event-oriented,reactive, flow based programming  heavily inspired by hardware chip design. I think I have reached the buzzword limit ;). Thanks so much!

Comment: Though you have exactly captured the intent of my question, I feel that my question was wrong. I think I have formulated it better over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576395/erlang-otp-how-to-notify-parent-process-that-child-processes-are-idle-and-no-mes. I did not want to change the question as you have given an excellent answer.