# Erlang/OTP How to notify parent process that child processes are idle and no messages in their mailbox

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I would like to design a process hierarchy where there is a a parent process P which acts like a gatekeeper and delegates the work(messages/events from its client processes) to it's children processes C1,C2..Cn which collaborate with each other and may send  the result back to P. The children processes cannot talk to any process outside, only P.

The challenge is that though P may have multiple messages from its clients, it should accept only one message, delegate the work to C1..Cn and ONLY accept the next message from its clients

- when all its children processes are done(or idle) and there are no more messages circulating between C1 to Cn.
- P finishes accepting messages from C1..Cn so that it can return the result to its clients

Constraints:

- Idle for me is when they are waiting with a receive (blocking) or simply exited.
- C1 to Cn are finite state machines. Some or all of them may send messages back to C. Or there may be no messages to be sent back to C. Even if no messages are sent back to C, C has to figure out that all of them are done with no messages between them.
- If any of C1 to Cn have been pre-empted, then it is considered busy(this may be obvious but I thought I'll put it here for completion) and C will not receive the next message

Is there an OTP pattern or library which will do this for me (before I hack something?). I know that `process_info` can let me know if the mailbox of a process are empty and I could keep on checking the children's mailboxes from P but it would be unnecessary polling from P.

EDIT GENERAL: I am trying to implement a reactive variant of [Flow Based Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming) on the Erlang platform. This has the notion of 'hierarchical processes' or composites which themselves may contain composite processes until we reach some boxes of actual code...I am going to research(looking at monitor,process_info,process_flag)  but I wanted to respond to your excellent answers

EDIT RECURSIVE PARENTS: Each of C1 and Cn can themselves be parent/composite processes. If I just spawn processes and let them exit immediately, I'll have to create the chain of Composites everytime as C1..Cn may themselves be composites (which spawn composites..and so on). Finally, when we reach a leaf box(which is not a composite node), they are supposed to be finite state machines.. so I'm not sure of spawning and making them exit quickly if the are FSMs.

EDIT TKOWAL: Since I am trying to create a generic parent/composite process, it does not know 'when' the task ends. All it does is relay the messages it receives from its children to it's siblings with the 'constraint' that it will not accept the next message from its client/siblings until its children are 'done'. The children C1..Cn may send not just one but many messages. I understand from your proposal, that wait_for_task_finish will stop blocking the moment it gets the first message. But more messages may be emitted too by P's children. P should wait for all messages. Also, having a task_end symbol will not work for the same reason(i.e. multiple messages possible from the children)

Answer (score 2):

Given how inexpensive it is to start up Erlang processes, your gatekeeper could start new children for each incoming task, and then wait for them all to exit normally once they complete their work.

But in general, it sounds like you're looking for a process pool. There are a few of these already available, such as [poolboy](https://github.com/devinus/poolboy) and [sidejob](https://github.com/basho/sidejob). Pools can be [harder to get right than you think](http://vagabond.github.io/programming/2012/01/21/quickchecking-poolboy-for-fun-and-profit/), so I advise using an existing proven pool implementation before attempting to write your own.

Comment: I oversimplified my question causing confusion. Please see EDIT GENERAL and EDIT RECURSIVE PARENTS

Answer (score 1):

After edits, this became entirely different question, so I am posting new answer.

If you are trying to write Flow Based Programming, then you are probably solving wrong problem.  FBP is effective, because almost everything is asynchronous and you start processing next request immediately after you finished with previous one.

So, the answer is - don't wait for children to finish:

> In FBP, there is no time dependencies between the components. So if I
>   have a chunk of data, it should be able to flow from one end of the
>   diagram to the other regardless of how any other pieces of data are
>   being handled. In order to program an FBP system, you have to minimize
>   your dependencies.

[source](https://flowbasedprogramming.wordpress.com/article/flow-based-programming/)

When creating parent and children, you know all the connections between blocks, so just configure children to send processed data directly to next block. For example: P1 has children C1 and C2. You send message to P1, it delegates it to C1, packet flows couple of times between C1 and C2 and after that, C1 or C2 sends it directly to P2.

Blocks should be stateless. They output should not depend on previous requests, so even if C1 and C2 are processing data from two different requests to P1 - it is OK. There could be situations, where P1 gets data packet D1 and then D2, but will output answers in different order R2 and then R1. It is also OK. You can use Erlang [reference](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id69034) to tag messages and then check, which response is from which request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, there is ready library for that, but it is really easy to hack, unless I missed something. Your P process should look like this:

```
ready_for_next_task() ->
    receive
        {task, Task, CallerPid} ->
            send_task_to_workers(Task)
    end,
    wait_for_task_finish(CallerPid).

wait_for_task_finish(CallerPid) ->
    receive
        {task_end, Response} ->
            CallerPid ! Response
    end,
    ready_for_next_task().
```

In `wait_for_task_finish/1` you have only one clause for receive, so it will not accept next task, until current one is finished. If you are waiting for multiple responses from workers, you can simply add second clause to `receive` with some partial response and call `wait_for_task_finish/1` recursively.

It is always better to have some indicator, that the processing ended, because you don't have guarantees on message delivery time. This means, that you could check, that all processes currently are waiting for message and think, that they ended processing, but actually, they did not started yet or one of them send message to other and you caught them before the second one had it in message box.

If the processes C1..Cn have only parts of actual work and don't know about the progress, than the gatekeeper P should know how many parts there were, receive all of them one by one and then call `ready_for_next_task/1`.

Comment: I oversimplified my question causing confusion. Please see EDIT GENERAL and EDIT TKOWAL